# In java - Grouping similar values

Tags: java, math, cluster-analysis, classification

First of all,thanks for reading my question.

I used [TF/IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%2didf) then on those values, I calculated cosine similarity to see how many documents are more similar. You can see the following matrix. Column names are like doc1, doc2, doc3 and rows names are same like doc1, doc2, doc3 etc. With the help of following matrix, I can see that doc1 and doc4 has 72% similarity (0.722711142). It is correct even if I see both documents they are similar. I have 1000 documents and I can see each document freq. in matrix to see how many of them are similar.
I used different clustering like k-means and agnes ( hierarchy) to combine them. It made clusters. For example Cluster1 has (doc4, doc5, doc3) becoz they have values (0.722711142, 0.602301766, 0.69912109) more close respectively. But when I see manually if these 3 documents are realy same so they are NOT. :( What am I doing or should I use something else other than clustering??????

```
    1             0.067305859  -0.027552299   0.602301766   0.722711142    
    0.067305859   1             0.048492904   0.029151952  -0.034714695 
   -0.027552299   0.748492904   1             0.610617214   0.010912109    
    0.602301766   0.029151952  -0.061617214   1             0.034410392    
    0.722711142  -0.034714695   0.69912109    0.034410392   1
```

P.S: The values can be wrong, it is just to give you an idea.
If you have any question please do ask.
Thanks

Comment: any tip?? any help??????????????????????

Comment: minor question: existing solutions to that problem cannot be applied or why do you develop it from scratch? My feeling says that lucene (or solr) should have implemented this as well ...

Comment: Well, what lucene or solr do. I already did it. Now I have CSV file but  my question is different. If you can explain your question. I can answer it in more better way

Comment: Somethihng seems amiss with the matrix. It has some weird non-symmetries to it. For your example cluster m[3,4] is -0.062 but m[4,3] is 0.611 and m[3,5] is 0.035 but m[5,3] is 0.699.

Comment: GeoffReedy please read my last line. I said i edit this matrix to give you an idea what I want to do. The values can have problems

Comment: I don't really understand your approach. You cluster the documents based on all the similarity values they have with *all* other documents? Only *a pair* of documents can have a similarity value. What you should be doing is cluster based on the (normalized) term frequencies, not sim. values. The fact that doc3 and doc4 contain sim. values in the same range doesn't tell you anything because these values are with respect to different other documents (doc3 to doc5 and doc4 to doc1). If I understood you wrong, please explain which features you use for clustering.

Comment: you understand 100% correct that `The fact that doc3 and doc4 contain sim. values in the same range doesn't tell you anything because these values are with respect to different other documents (doc3 to doc5 and doc4 to doc1).` so if you have any solution for this problem plz let me know

Comment: The more I look at the questions you've asked on SO, the more I get the impression you'd like the community do your term project or something similar. Considering that you asked 24 questions, did only 11 upvotes but 6 downvotes, I'll go by 'you get what you give' from here on ... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with TF/IDF, but the process can go wrong in many stages generally:

1, Did you remove stopwords?

2, Did you apply stemming? Porter stemmer for example.

3, Did you normalize frequencies for document length? (Maybe the TFIDF thing has a solution for that, I don't know)

4, Clustering is a discovery method but not a holy grail. The documents it retrieves as a group may be related more or less, but that depends on the data, tuning, clustering algorithm, etc.

What do you want to achieve? What is your setup?
Good luck!

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I used all the things you mentioned above. I have a big similarity matrix and I want to group all the similar documents now. For example if 10 docments are similar to document 15 so there should be one cluster which contain 11 docs ( 1 to 10 and 15 doc) but clustering work on distance and it group the doc. which has freq. more closers lets say 70% while all of the document in that cluster are different :(
Is there any other tech. you can mention?

Comment: The right clustering method depends much on the distribution of your document space. You could try the CURE algorithm, or DENCLUE. Or there are clusterings which work on the graph representation of the connectivity data, like Markov Clustering (http://www.micans.org/mcl/)

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be not to use pre-calculated similarity values at all, because the similarity between docs should be found by the clustering algorithm itself. I would simply set up a feature space with one column per term in the corpus, so that the number of columns equals the size of the vocabulary (minus stop word, if you want). Each feature value contains the relative frequency of the respective term in that document. I guess you could use tf*idf values as well, although I wouldn't expect that to help too much. Depending on the clustering algorithm you use, the discriminating power of a particular term should be found automatically, i.e. if a term appears in all documents with a similar relative frequency, then that term does not discriminate well between the classes and the algorithm should detect that.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't understand. For my calculation, I am calculating similarity basis on LSI and VSM. Clustering can't help in similarity. If it does please explain which one and how?

Comment: In clustering, a doc is a point in a feature space and a resp. algorithm groups data points which are close to one another. If the features are word frequencies, then docs that contain the same words, i.e. *similar* docs, will be in the same group(s). This is all clustering is about: grouping similar data points (here: documents), where similarity depends on the features employed. I think chapters 16 to 18 in this book: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html will guide you well (it's freely available online).